# Counting new values not occuring earlier and not occuring in last group

Tags: r, count, dplyr, window

I am trying to count number of unique "new" users per month. New is a user that has not appeared before (since the beginning) I am also trying to count number of unique users not appearing last month.

The original data looks like

```
library(dplyr)
    date <- c("2010-01-10","2010-02-13","2010-03-22","2010-01-11","2010-02-14","2010-03-23","2010-01-12","2010-02-14","2010-03-24")
    mth <- rep(c("2010-01","2010-02","2010-03"),3)
    user <- c("123","129","145","123","129","180","180","184","145")

    dt <- data.frame(date,mth,user)

    dt <- dt %>% arrange(date)

    dt

       date     mth user
1 2010-01-10 2010-01  123
2 2010-01-11 2010-01  123
3 2010-01-12 2010-01  180
4 2010-02-13 2010-02  129
5 2010-02-14 2010-02  129
6 2010-02-14 2010-02  184
7 2010-03-22 2010-03  145
8 2010-03-23 2010-03  180
9 2010-03-24 2010-03  145
```

The answer should look like

```
    new <- c(2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1)
    totNew <- c(2,2,2,4,4,4,5,5,5)
    notLastMonth <- c(2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2)

    tmp <- cbind(dt,new,totNew,notLastMonth)
    tmp

        date     mth user new totNew notLastMonth
1 2010-01-10 2010-01  123   2      2            2
2 2010-01-11 2010-01  123   2      2            2
3 2010-01-12 2010-01  180   2      2            2
4 2010-02-13 2010-02  129   2      4            2
5 2010-02-14 2010-02  129   2      4            2
6 2010-02-14 2010-02  184   2      4            2
7 2010-03-22 2010-03  145   1      5            2
8 2010-03-23 2010-03  180   1      5            2
9 2010-03-24 2010-03  145   1      5            2
```

Comment: Is there a reason you want the new, totnew and notLastMonth for the overall numbers to be in this "user" table... seems odd to store that inside a user record.  Getting the new customers is straightforward though, group by user, and mutate a new column which gives you the first month they appeared in. Then group by that new column, and count users.

Answer (score 6):

Here's an attempt (explanations within the body of the code)

```
dt %>%
  group_by(user) %>%
  mutate(Count = row_number()) %>% # Count appearances per user
  group_by(mth) %>%
  mutate(new = sum(Count == 1)) %>% # Count first appearances per months
  summarise(new = first(new), # Summarise new users per month (for cumsum)
            users = list(unique(user))) %>% # Create a list of unique users per month (for notLastMonth)
  mutate(totNew = cumsum(new), # Calculate overall cummulative sum of unique users
         notLastMonth = lengths(Map(setdiff, users, lag(users)))) %>% # Compare new users to previous month
  select(-users) %>%
  right_join(dt) # Join back to the real data

# A tibble: 9 × 6
#       mth   new totNew notLastMonth       date   user
#    <fctr> <int>  <int>        <int>     <fctr> <fctr>
# 1 2010-01     2      2            2 2010-01-10    123
# 2 2010-01     2      2            2 2010-01-11    123
# 3 2010-01     2      2            2 2010-01-12    180
# 4 2010-02     2      4            2 2010-02-13    129
# 5 2010-02     2      4            2 2010-02-14    129
# 6 2010-02     2      4            2 2010-02-14    184
# 7 2010-03     1      5            2 2010-03-22    145
# 8 2010-03     1      5            2 2010-03-23    180
# 9 2010-03     1      5            2 2010-03-24    145
```

Comment: This worked as adverised. Great use of dplyr, grouping and mutating several times, clever. Thank you so much! Have not seen the use of notLastMonth = lengths(Map(setdiff, users, lag(users)))) before.

Answer (score 4):

Here's another idea starting with tabulating "user" per "mth":

```
table(dt[c("user", "mth")]) > 0L
```

Assuming that this path is very likely to lead to memory problems, we could start with the sparse alternative:

```
library(Matrix)
tab = as(xtabs( ~ user + mth, dt, sparse = TRUE) > 0L, "TsparseMatrix")
tab
#5 x 3 sparse Matrix of class "lgTMatrix"
#    2010-01 2010-02 2010-03
#123       |       .       .
#129       .       |       .
#145       .       .       |
#180       |       .       |
#184       .       |       .
```

Then, having the "mth" (as column index) each "user" first appeared:

```
tapply(tab@j, rownames(tab)[tab@i + 1L], min) + 1L
#123 129 145 180 184 
#  1   2   3   1   2
```

we can find the number of new entries per "mth":

```
new = setNames(tabulate(tapply(tab@j, rownames(tab)[tab@i + 1L], min) + 1L, 
                        ncol(tab)), 
               colnames(tab))
new
#2010-01 2010-02 2010-03 
#      2       2       1
```

and the cumulative sum of new entries:

```
totNew = cumsum(new)
totNew
#2010-01 2010-02 2010-03 
#      2       4       5
```

And, subtracting the number of "user" per "mth" that exist both in a "mth" and its previous:

```
setNames(colSums(cbind(FALSE, tab[, -ncol(tab)]) & tab), colnames(tab))
#2010-01 2010-02 2010-03 
#      0       0       0
```

from the number of users per month:

```
colSums(tab)
#2010-01 2010-02 2010-03 
#      2       2       2
```

we get:

```
notLast = colSums(tab) - colSums(cbind(FALSE, tab[, -ncol(tab)]) & tab)
notLast
#2010-01 2010-02 2010-03 
#      2       2       2
```

One way to reach to the desired output could be:

```
merge(dt, data.frame(mth = names(new), new, totNew, notLast), by = "mth")
#      mth       date user new totNew notLast
#1 2010-01 2010-01-10  123   2      2       2
#2 2010-01 2010-01-11  123   2      2       2
#3 2010-01 2010-01-12  180   2      2       2
#4 2010-02 2010-02-13  129   2      4       2
#5 2010-02 2010-02-14  129   2      4       2
#6 2010-02 2010-02-14  184   2      4       2
#7 2010-03 2010-03-22  145   1      5       2
#8 2010-03 2010-03-23  180   1      5       2
#9 2010-03 2010-03-24  145   1      5       2
```

Comment: Thank you for your great effort. What we can see through all of these solutions is that R is a highly flexible (and hence often bevildering) programming language. Looking at these solutions you would be hard pressed to tell that they came from the same programming language unless you were intimately familiar with all of the packages and extenxions that R offers.

Answer (score 3):

Since no one posted it yet, here's my preferred way:

```
library(zoo)
dt <- dt %>% mutate(ym = as.yearmon(mth))

ct_dt = dt %>% distinct(user, ym) %>% arrange(user, ym) %>%
  group_by(user) %>% mutate(last_ym = dplyr::lag(ym)) %>%
  group_by(ym) %>% summarise(
    new         = sum(is.na(last_ym)), 
    not_last_ym = sum(is.na(last_ym) | 12*(ym - last_ym) > 1)
  )

# # A tibble: 3 x 3
#              ym   new not_last_ym
#   <S3: yearmon> <int>       <int>
# 1      Jan 2010     2           2
# 2      Feb 2010     2           2
# 3      Mar 2010     1           2
```

From here, you can take the `cumsum` of `new` if you really want the `totNew` column; and you can `left_join` `ct_dt` with `dt` if you really want to view these data (confusingly) stretched out over multiple rows.

---

Or with data.table...

```
library(zoo)
library(data.table)
setDT(dt)

dt[, ym := as.yearmon(mth)]

ct_dt = setorder(unique(dt[, .(user, ym)]))[,
  last_ym := shift(ym)
, by=user][, .(
  new         = sum(is.na(last_ym)), 
  not_last_ym = sum(is.na(last_ym) | 12*(ym - last_ym) > 1)
), by=ym]
```

Comment: I tried this on my larger dataset. I got correct results for "new" but not for "not_last_ym", I am sure it only require a small change. Thanks.

Comment: @user3482393 If you can add a small example that illustrates the problem to your initial post, maybe I can figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a pure base R solution. It works best when the variables are not factors and assumes that the data is sorted by month.

```
# get list of active monthly users
activeUsers <- lapply(unique(dt$mth), function(i) unique(dt[dt$mth==i, "user"]))
# get accumulating list of all users
allUsers <- Reduce(union, activeUsers, accumulate=TRUE)
```

Now, all monthly users are stored in activeUsers and a growing list of all users up to a given month is stored in allUsers. With this information, we can easily calculate the first two variables.

```
# get the calculations
totNew <- lengths(allUsers)
new <- c(totNew[1], diff(totNew))
notLastMonth <- c(totNew[1], lengths(lapply(seq_along(activeUsers)[-1],
                                 function(i) setdiff(activeUsers[[i]], activeUsers[[i-1]]))))
```

The `lengths` function efficiently calculates the length of each list item. The second line uses `diff` to calculate the number of new users. Both the second and third lines prepend the initial value (2) using the totNew variable. The third line is a bit more involved and uses `setdiff` and `lapply` to construct the set of active users in a month not present in the previous month. `lengths` is again used to count.

```
#merge on to data set
merge(dt, data.frame(mth=unique(dt$mth), new=new, totNew=totNew, notLastMonth=notLastMonth),
      by="mth")

      mth       date user new totNew notLastMonth
1 2010-01 2010-01-10  123   2      2            2
2 2010-01 2010-01-12  180   2      2            2
3 2010-01 2010-01-11  123   2      2            2
4 2010-02 2010-02-13  129   2      4            2
5 2010-02 2010-02-14  129   2      4            2
6 2010-02 2010-02-14  184   2      4            2
7 2010-03 2010-03-23  180   1      5            2
8 2010-03 2010-03-22  145   1      5            2
9 2010-03 2010-03-24  145   1      5            2
```

**data**

```
dt <- data.frame(date,mth,user, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: This also worked on my much larger dataset. Interesting use of functions and lists. For summarizing information, I have been using dplyr extensively, but this is certainly a great way of using base R to get the same result. Thanks.